# Authenticating Dropbox in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, authentication, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am adding Dropbox support to my iOS application. Using the official Dropbox API and the tutorials  [online here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start) I have gotten to the point where Dropbox needs to be authenticated. The code below is what is given to Authenticate when a button is pressed:

```
//MainViewController.m
....
@implementation CryptoMainViewController
.....
#pragma mark - Dropbox
- (void)didPressLink {
    if (![[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
        [[DBSession sharedSession] link];
    }
}
```

But no matter how I change the code, where I put it or what button I link it to, nothing will happen. Using breakpoints I've found that the method does in-fact get triggered. I've even put it in an IBAction, but this gives the same result. What am I doing wrong? **How can I get my app to authenticate the end-user?**

And, once authenticated, **How can I save an NSString to the user's Dropbox?**

If this is just totally wrong, then where can I go to find resources on how to do this properly?

The whole tutorial, all of the documentation, api, etc. is available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/authentication#ios).

Comment: If you put a breakpoint at the start of this method, does it ever get triggered?

Comment: @quixoto Yes, it does get triggered with Breakpoints

Comment: Check whether you have given the app key in info.plist?
Your app key is also needed in Info.plist file so the app can register for the correct url scheme

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem; the reason was that I hadn't set the shared Dropbox session, e.g.

```
DBSession* dbSession = [[[DBSession alloc] initWithAppKey: @"your_app_key"
                                           appSecret: @"your_app_secret"
                                           root: kDBRootAppFolder] autorelease];
[DBSession setSharedSession: dbSession];
```

Once that was called the link worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

this answer may be late but im guessing that you already linked your app before and want to do so again. The only way you can have the process of linking taking place again is if you run the following code:
  [[DBSession sharedSession] unlinkAll];
You can place it in your viewDidLoad. When you then call didPressLink: the app should open up dropbox app(if available), safari or an in app window asking for your permission to access your dropbox. If this does not happen then the problem is somewhere else. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Does your view implement the `<DBLoginControllerDelegate>` ?

If so, link Dropbox like so:

```
DBLoginController* controller = [[DBLoginController new] autorelease];
        controller.delegate = self;
        [controller presentFromController:self];
```

Comment: Hmmm.... are you sure <DBLoginControllerDelegate> is the right one, because even with all the right Headers imported I still get errors: "Cannot find protocol declaration"

Comment: I believe he's referring to the `DBRestClientDelegate` protocol. Also, where are you calling the didPressLink method from? You may need to provide us with some more code.

Comment: I am sure, because I did this for our application, Securis.

Comment: @serb the didPressLink method is being called from MainViewController.m

Comment: I believe the login controller stuff is from an older version of the DB SDK. THe sharedSession's -link should be sufficient now.